# Reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 and restored ZFS array but can’t see data

Tags: raid, zfs, plex

I have just reinstalled Ubuntu 18.04 with a fresh install which is sitting on my SSD drive. I also have an existing array which I’m trying to get to. Installed ZFS and restored array (mordor) and Linux sees everything fine. I have installed Plex server and when I try to add the media from mordor, it cannot see the array. I’m not sure if it’s a rights issue or not. In the GUI files icon, I do not see the array but I can dig deeper and find it. In terminal, it shows the array is healthy.

I do have the data backed up to an external hdd (RAID is not a backup). I had this working before the system reinstallation but not sure if I should just reformat arrays and start over.

Comment: Plex is Probably the issue. I help out on a Plex m3u Proxy called xTeVe, and users have to sometimes wipe the plex database before it reloads Network shares.

Comment: I SUDO ZPOOL STATUS and everything is showing online with no known data errors.

I can then type "DIR" and the directory is not showing.
I type LS -L and see the directory however in the GUI, it does not show up so could it be a right's issue?

I cannot load a .JPG or .PNG file here to show you what I see

Comment: Could be, the Plex user will have to have R/W Access to all the shares. Usermod Plex?

Comment: I can't even get the Plex server to see the media.  This is at the very beginning stages where I can't see the media to add into Plex.  I didn't have this issue prior to reinstalling the OS.

Comment: I am trying to add the libraries which are sitting in the array "mordor".  When I click on "Add Library" - I see all the other directories there but "mordor" is not visible.  I'm not sure what i need to do.

Comment: I'm a very Novice to Ubuntu, Linux and Perms but wouldn't changing the perms of "mordor" to 777 allow complete access to everything? `chmod 777 /mordor` `hts@DESKTOP-OF0H6L3:~$ chmod 777 DirectTV` `drwxrwxrwx 1 hts  hts         512 Sep  6 01:32 DirectTV` I think Plex creates a user called Plex so that would need to have access `chmod plex:plex 777 mordor` forgive me if I'm way off. lol

Comment: I am not sure what this might be:

hts@DESKTOP-OF0H6L3:~$ chmod 777 DirectTV drwxrwxrwx 1 hts hts 512 Sep 6 01:32 DirectTV

Comment: I was just showing how I made access to everything to a Directory in my file system. This may be out of your scope for Linux use and will take some learning of Linux file structure and Perms